# How to determine the thread-group and thread-size I should use for Metal vertex compute

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, metal

I am very new to Metal compute and am trying to wrap my mind around the concepts of threads and groups. The problem is that most if not all the examples use a 2d texture as an example which is totally not what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a compute function that takes in 2 points and a few floats in one buffer and computes 4 points and puts them in another buffer so:

```
  |--------Buffer1------|      |-------Buffer2-----------|
f(point1, point2, [floats])=point1, point2, point3, point4
f is a function essentially involving some linear algebra with some multiplication 
and addition. The most costly part being a sqrt operation used to normalize 
the vector between point1 and point2. No branches in code.
```

I know roughly how to write the kernel function but I have no idea how to assign threads and thread-groups to it because I don't know how to compute a potentially optimal amounts for this scenario.

Comment: Mostly, you don't need to care about thread groups. Just use the algorithm that Apple shows in their [Calculating Threadgroup and Grid Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/compute_processing/calculating_threadgroup_and_grid_sizes) article. For your case, where you have a 1D buffer to process, just consider the "texture.height" from the examples as 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign threads and threadgroups however you want, i.e. use them in whatever way makes the most sense for your logic.

Figuring out what the best number of threads and groups is, can be a bit of trial and error. But a good place to start is to use one thread per unique thing that you want to compute.

In your case one thread for every `f(point1, point2, [floats])` seems reasonable (so that one thread will write four points to the output buffer). But you haven't been very specific about your function `f()` so perhaps a different way to assign threads makes more sense. I don't have enough info to make a good recommendation.

(Note: There *is* a limit to how many threads you can use in a single group. This depends on the device. So if you need more threads than that, you have to split them up into multiple groups.)